# Como arredondar um número para o maior valor no Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, funções

Eu estava fazendo alguns testes no MySQL e então surgiu a necessidade de ter que arredondar um número para o maior. Seria algo tipo:

```
if($numero == 1.5){
    $numero = 2;
}
```

Apesar de eu poder fazer assim, eu queria evitar ficar fazendo `if`/ `else`.

Não existe uma função que faça isso no MySQL? Por exemplo uma função que se o valor digitado fosse 1.5 arredonda-se para o maior, para 2 no caso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acredito que você procura pela função [`CEILING(X)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceiling). Essa função `CEILING()`, que pode ser usada abreviadamente como [`CEIL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceil), retorna o menor valor inteiro não inferior a X.

Falando em outras palavras, "*arredonda o maior/arredonda pra cima*" um valor.

Veja alguns exemplos de retorno:

```
mysql> SELECT CEILING(1.5);
            -> 2
mysql> SELECT CEILING(-2.3);
            -> -2
mysql> SELECT CEIL(7.83);
            -> 8
mysql> SELECT CEIL(10.5244655448);
            -> 11
```

Pode ver este [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92537/2) que demonstra uma das maneiras de realizar o que você quer.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar a função [`ROUND()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round), passando o valor e/ou quantidade de casas decimais como parâmetro. Veja alguns exemplos:

Passando somente o valor como parâmetro:

```
mysql>SELECT ROUND(2.5); 
->resultado: 3
```

Passando o valor e a quantidade de casas decimais, lembrando que se usar o `ROUND(x, 0)` seria equivalente a `ROUND(x)`. Veja:

```
mysql>SELECT ROUND(2.5, 0); 
->resultado: 3
mysql>SELECT ROUND(1.5, 0); 
->resultado: 2
mysql>SELECT ROUND(1.6667, 0); 
->resultado: 2
mysql>SELECT ROUND(1.6667, 1); 
->resultado: 1.7
mysql>SELECT ROUND(1.6667, 2); 
->resultado: 1.67
```

Veja [funcionando no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80ba5/3).

Para mais detalhes, veja na [na documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round).

Comment: @LucasLopes Se você ROUND(1.5, 0); ele vai arredondar para 2 amigo. Seria 0 casas decimais.

Answer (score 3):

Use a função [ceiling(x)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceil)??

```
SELECT CEILING(1.23);
//retorno: 2
```